# Can I install Windows 8.1 on my laptop with an Intel i5 8250u CPU?

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, cpu

Recently I got a new laptop, the Dell Inspiron 15 5570 with the following specs:

- Core i5 8250u 1.6 GHz
- 4 GB DDR4
- AMD Radeon 530 2 GB GDDR5

Before this I was using an old PC with Windows 7 on it. Never bothered to update since it did all the work I needed it to do. However, the new laptop runs Windows 10 and I soon saw how horrific it was so I'm planning to downgrade.

Now I am thinking about going to Windows 8.1, since 7 may be a bit too old. But I have heard that 8.1 does not support the latest 8th gen CPUs so I may run into problems. Is this true? What can I do to solve this particular problem?

Comment: I’m really not sure you will like Windows 8 any more than Windows 10.

Comment: @JamesP - agree.  hacker804 - why don't you give Windows 10 a try for a couple of months before you move?  I didn't like Windows 10 at first, but now I'm used to it, it's the best Windows OS so far.  Windows 7 was amazing.  Windows 8 was terrible.  Windows 8.1 was only a little better.  Windows 10 started off on thin ice, but now I'm used to it, it's the best so far.  Biggest problem with W10 is it's too 'user friendly'.  Try it for a bit first, you may save yourself some time if you find it's ok - plus everyone will have to move to W10 sooner or later.

Comment: I noticed you are using i5 (6th generation processor), it is supported by Windows 8.1, also it is support Windows 10. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/windows-processor-requirements

Comment: Windows 10 is kinda like Windows 7 with elements of Windows 8.x.  If you liked 7 but not 10, then you probably don't like the parts that came from 8.x.

Comment: Can you? Probably.
Should you: ABSOLUTELY NOT! Go for win 10 (less resource needs than 8) as far as I know, and also not a complete disaster

Answer (score 3):

To check if you CPU is compatible with Windows 8.1 is easy, just look it up [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005771/processors.html). There is a step by step description on how to do it.

Although the CPU is compatible with Windows 8.1, the fact is that Windows 8.1 does not support that processor. Windows 8.1 only supports up to 6th generation Intel Core processors. See [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/windows-processor-requirements).

Although it might be possible to install Windows if updated drivers are available for the CPU by Dell or Intel. This way  it will start up and run but you will most likely get an error when you try to update Windows and if you have an unsupported processor, [see this article here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4012982/the-processor-is-not-supported-together-with-the-windows-version-that).